# Are messages in Ruby an implementation detail or fundamental

Tags: ruby

My understanding is that method calls on a Ruby object are sending messages to the object (which could be done manually using the `send` method).

When I use Python, I don't think about how a method/function call is processed; if it's defined or available then it executes, otherwise I get an error.

1) Is Ruby's use of messages unique (i.e. is Python also using messages under the hood)?

2) Is Ruby's use of messages just an implementation detail or is it fundamental to how you're supposed to use Ruby (i.e. will I be missing out on something if I ignore it and go on calling my methods like in Python)?

Comment: Can you provide a readable example please?

Comment: I feel like this question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Are messages unique to Ruby?

This idea of calling methods as sending messages is **not** unique to Ruby, it's an ideology that stems from [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Messages) from which Ruby inherits many ideas. As a result, other descendants of Smalltalk also use a message based dispatch system (e.g. Objective-C, Groovy, and **yes, Python uses it too**). Smalltalk is one of the very first OOP languages, and was very much a trend setter for the paradigm, so you will see many of its ideas in other languages.

#### Other OOP languages

Other languages (especially ones that promote OOP) also (sort of) use messages under different guises (like "virtual function call", or "dynamic dispatch" in C++ and Java respectively). The difference here is that you the programmer do not get to access the messages directly, they are an implementation detail of the language, and not your program's, so if you send an unsupported message in C++ or Java, it will cause an error (at runtime).

#### Messages in Ruby

The point being made about Ruby is that the methods you can call (the messages you can send) do not depend on the type of the object you are calling them on. You can send any message to any object, but those who don't have that message implemented as a method will end up doing whatever their `method_missing` tells them to. This means you get to control what happens when an unsupported message comes through (if you want).

## 2. Should this change how I write programs in Ruby?

The short answer is yes. But the thing is that it probably already has: Ruby is not statically typed, so there is no way of knowing what methods you can call on an object held in a variable anyway (there are no "compile time" guarantees). Furthermore, knowing that message passing is being used under the hood, allows you (when you need to) to override the implementation of `method_missing` to produce some very expressive classes. The Rails framework does this to implement some of its DSL.

## Addendum. Don't Abuse it!

Like with anything, this feature can be abused. It is *possible* to only ever write one method in your classes (`method_missing`) and then write all your method definitions in there. But the more logic that you put in `method_missing` the harder your class becomes to understand. So, if you can, define a method, and treat this sort of metaprogramming as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks asQuirreL, that was a very comprehensive answer.  I didn't realize Python uses messages too.

Comment: Well, in python a method for an object is just an attribute of the object (just like all the other properties). So if you define `__getattr__` on the class you can get `method_missing` like behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Messages are fundamental, not just in Ruby, but in OO in general.

The term "Object-Orientation" was invented by Alan Kay, and he defines it [this way](http://www.purl.org/stefan_ram/pub/doc_kay_oop_en):

> OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things.

In more modern terms:

- messaging
- encapsulation
- late-binding

Implementation-wise, messaging is a late-bound procedure call, and if procedure calls are late-bound, then you cannot know at design time *what* you are going to call, so you cannot make any assumptions about the concrete representation of state. So, really it is about messaging, late-binding is an implementation of messaging and encapsulation is a consequence of it.

He later on clarified that "[The big idea is 'messaging'](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev/1998-October/017019.html)", and regrets having called it "object-oriented" instead of "message-oriented", because the term "object-oriented" puts the focus on the unimportant thing (objects) and distracts from what is really important (messaging):

> Just a gentle reminder that I took some pains at the last OOPSLA to try to remind everyone that Smalltalk is not only NOT its syntax or the class library, it is not even about classes. I'm sorry that I long ago coined the term "objects" for this topic because it gets many people to focus on the lesser idea.
>
> The big idea is "messaging" -- that is what the kernal of Smalltalk/Squeak is all about (and it's something that was never quite completed in our Xerox PARC phase). The Japanese have a small word -- ma -- for "that which is in between" -- perhaps the nearest English equivalent is "interstitial". The key in making great and growable systems is much more to design how its modules communicate rather than what their internal properties and behaviors should be. Think of the internet -- to live, it (a) has to allow many different kinds of ideas and realizations that are beyond any single standard and (b) to allow varying degrees of safe interoperability between these ideas.

(Of course, today, most people don't even focus on objects but on classes, which is even more wrong.)

Messaging is *fundamental* to OO, both as metaphor and as a mechanism.

If you send someone a message, you don't know what they do with it. The *only* thing you can observe, is their response. You don't know whether they processed the message themselves (i.e. if the object has a method), if they forwarded the message to someone else (delegation / proxying), if they even understood it. That's what encapsulation is all about, that's what OO is all about. You cannot even distinguish a proxy from the real thing, as long as it responds how you expect it to.

A more "modern" term for "messaging" is "dynamic method dispatch" or "virtual method call", but that loses the metaphor and focuses on the mechanism.

Similar points are also made in [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/) and also his [*Proposal for Simplified, Modern Definitions of "Object" and "Object Oriented"*](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/2012/07/proposal-for-simplified-modern.html).

> Dynamic dispatch of operations is the essential characteristic of objects. It means that the operation to be invoked is a dynamic property of the object itself. Operations cannot be identified statically, and there is no way in general to exactly what operation will executed in response to a given request, except by running it. This is exactly the same as with first-class functions, which are always dynamically dispatched.

In Smalltalk-72, there weren't even any objects! There were *only* message streams that got parsed, rewritten and rerouted. First came methods (standard ways to parse and reroute the message streams), later came objects (groupings of methods that share some private state). Inheritance came much later, and classes were only introduced as a way to support inheritance. Had Kay's research group already known about prototypes, they probably would have never introduced classes in the first place.

Comment: I wish I'd read this explanation a couple of years ago when I was first learning about OOP.  Makes a lot more sense than the Java taxonomy of classes approach I learned then.

Comment: @CollinMeyers: those are important and interesting but orthogonal. You can have taxonomy and inheritance with ADTs and you can have OO without taxonomy or inheritance. Inheritance is for incremental refinement and reducing code duplication. It is nice (even outside OO) but not necessary for OO.

Comment: +1 for explaining how exactly is message passing a fancy thing in CS, +7 (if I could) for the parenthetical sentence "Of course, today, most people don't even focus on objects..."

Comment: And, btw., "Proposal for Simplified, Modern Definitions of Object..." is nothing else but duck typing.

Comment: Why is focusing on classes even 'more wrong' than focusing on objects?

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamental as a metaphor for the non-static evaluation of methods. Meaning e.g. a single instance can have extra methods, not defined in the class.

Or if a method is not known, it is handled by a special `method_missing` method. Which can be overruled to add "fake methods" which are never really defined, e.g. like `ActiveRecord` does when it dynamically will recognise attribute-names as methods.

So, unlike other "static" languages, there is a dynamic evaluation of methods, and that is why the metaphor of "sending a message", instead of merely "calling a function" is used. "calling a function" presumes the "address of the function" is known, while in ruby the evaluation of knowing which method to call, if any, is completely dynamic.

That being said: this is not important when starting out with ruby, and honestly for me personally this concept of "sending messages" confused me at first, because I just wanted to "call methods" :)

Comment: Thanks nathanvda.  Thinking about sending a message vs calling a function as being metaphors makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental. Message passing is a fancy buzzphrase in computer science, so Ruby is now this hot language based on message passing. But buzzwords aside, consider:

```
Array.class_exec do define_method "42" do self << 42 end end
```

An array won't let you write

```
[].42 #=> SyntaxError
```

But `42` is now nevertheless a valid message to which an array responds:

```
[].send "42" #=> [42]
```

In other words, if you don't think in terms of messages, you can't exploit 100% of Ruby power.

As for Python, whan calling a Python method, such as `foo.bar()`, what happens is that you get the method object first (`foo.bar`) and then, when you hold it by the nuts, you call it by `()`. In Ruby, you can get hold of the method by `foo.method( :bar )`, and then call it if you want by `.()`, such as:

```
x = [1]
x.method( "42" ).()
#=> [1, 42]
```

This makes the underlying message passing mechanics somewhat more explicit.